# PHP Cron Job not Executing

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I am trying to setup a cron job on my Linux server.

I have the following code

```
*/1 * * * * root php -f /var/www/html/includes/cron/cron.inc.a.php &> dev/php.log
```

The file the cron job is meant to call, gets a heartbeat response from another server.

```
<?php

    $l = new MySQLi();

    $l->connect(blah);

    $q = $l->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_latency_stats`");

    set_include_path('/var/www/html/includes/');

    include("ping/ping.php");

    $host = '<IP ADDRESS>';

    $ping = new Ping($host);

    $latency = $ping->ping();

    if (!is_bool($latency)){
        if(is_float($latency) || is_string($latency)) {
            if(is_string($latency)){
              $s = split(".", $latency);
              if($s[0] >= 100){
                $response_array['status'] = "success";
                $response_array['state'] = "WARNING"; 
                $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $response_array['response'] = "High Latency";
                $response_array['ping'] = "$latency";
                $response_array['message'] = "null";
              }else{
                $response_array['status'] = "success";
                $response_array['state'] = "UP"; 
                $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $response_array['response'] = "LIVE";
                $response_array['ping'] = "$latency";
                $response_array['message'] = "null";
              }
            }elseif(is_float($latency)){
              if($latency >= 100){
                $response_array['status'] = "success";
                $response_array['state'] = "WARNING"; 
                $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $response_array['response'] = "High Latency";
                $response_array['ping'] = "$latency";
                $response_array['message'] = "null";
              }else{
                $response_array['status'] = "success";
                $response_array['state'] = "UP"; 
                $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $response_array['response'] = "LIVE";
                $response_array['ping'] = "$latency";       
                $response_array['message'] = "null";    
              }             
            }
        }else{
            $response_array['status'] = "error";
            $response_array['state'] = "UNKONWN"; 
            $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $response_array['message'] = "Unexpected Response!";
            $response_array['response'] = "$latency";
            $response_array['ping'] = "null";       
        }
    }else {
        $response_array['status'] = "error";
        $response_array['state'] = "DOWN"; 
        $response_array['timedate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $response_array['message'] = "Request Unreachable!";
        $response_array['response'] = "$latency";
        $response_array['ping'] = "null";
    }                       

    $q = $l->query("INSERT INTO  `enigmaStat`.`tbl_latency_stats` (`latency_stat_id` ,`latency_stat_date_time` ,`latency_stat_status` ,`latency_stat_response` ,`latency_stat_latency_value` ,`latency_stat_user_text`)VALUES ('' , '".$response_array['timedate']."' ,  '".$response_array['state']."',  '".$response_array['response']."',  '".$response_array['ping']."',  '".$response_array['message']."')");


?>
```

But nothing inserts. I have run the file from the website path and manually through command line as follows:

```
php -f /var/www/html/includes/cron/cron.inc.a.php
```

and it inserts into the database.

I'm new to server configs etc. so I apologise if this is not detailed enough, I would be happy to add any details necessary to help solve the issue.

Thanks.

---

**Edit**

Following the wiki I have tried:

```
env -i sh -c 'php -f /var/www/html/includes/cron/cron.inc.a.php'
```

and it works and inserts into the database.

Comment: Could you go through the [Debugging Crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) section on crontab tag wiki and add any findings?

Comment: @thatotherguy I've run all the suggestions in the wiki, but no results. all environment emulations work. no log outputs. really not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional flags are sometimes required for a PHP cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * php -q /var/www/html/includes/cron/cron.inc.a.php &> dev/php.log
```

Comment: No Change @meda still no execution

Comment: @DavidPassmore oops, remove the `root` from there, when cron runs, it runs as a user